# mat-icon Angular don't appear

Tags: css, html5, angular, angular-material

I Import the Mat-Icon from Angular, but when i use then, he does not appear. Someone helps me?
Below my code:

app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatIconModule,
FlexLayoutModule,
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.hmtl:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TeslaAngular</title>
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.component.html when i call the mat-icon:

```
<footer fxLayoutAlign="center end">
  <button class="button"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon></button>
</footer>
```

When i used the mat-icon i my app.component.html, this appear in this form:
[Mat-icon error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28AN3.png)

Comment: olá, este é o site do SO em português, as perguntas aqui devem ser feitas nesse idioma

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa adicionar o caminho do arquivo de icones no `angular.json` na tag de `styles`. Você deve seguir o seguinte caminho: `projects -> "nome do projeto" -> architect -> options -> styles`.